# disable hg qfinish without changeset message

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I use mercurial queues and sometimes I forget to set my message with a `hg qrefresh -m ...` and forget to check before I run `hg qfinish` and I get the message `patch MyPatch finalized without changeset message`. Is there any way I can make qfinish abort if there is no message?

The only way I found to fix this after I do that is to generate a patch, `hg strip` my last revision, reapply the patch and then commit with my message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `hg qimport -r tip` to turn the last changeset (your finalized patch) in to a MQ patch again.

Comment: Much better idea than mine :)

Comment: I just used this command and its great. It solves my primary problem that lead to this question.

Comment: Asa: I'm glad you like it... though we should probably be smarter and let `hg qfinish` prompt you for a commit message in the same way that `hg commit` does if no message has been supplied already. See also http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2021

Answer (score 0):

One way around this problem is to add `-e` to the default options for `qrefresh` and `qnew`, in your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[defaults]
qrefresh = -e
qnew = -e
```

This way you can no longer forget to describe the patch.